# Why auto-complete from jquery does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Today I started to use JQuery. I found [this explanation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) of how to do it.

On that page I also have a complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/main.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/lib/jquery.bgiframe.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/lib/jquery.dimensions.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var data = "Core Selectors Attributes Traversing Manipulation CSS Events Effects Ajax Utilities".split(" ");
$("#example").autocomplete(data);
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  API Reference: <input id="example" /> (try "C" or "E")
</body>
</html>
```

I copy paste the code and it does not work. I have to mention that it works if I try it on the page that I have mentioned before (so JavaScripts are switched on in my browser).

I have to idea how to solve this problem because I have no error message and has no previous experience with the jquery. Can anybody help me with that?

**ADDED:**

I found a feature that can be important. When I load the above mentioned code/page, the auto-complete works as it is expected! If I reload the page, it change its appearance a bit (a space between the input field and top of the page appears) and auto-complete stops to work. Does it tell you something?

Comment: Well, it works for me. I'm using Firefox. Install Firebug, a great debugger for firefox. If you are going to work with jQuery, you'll sure need it.

Comment: It's not possible to accurately debug your problem with more information about your server setup. I would recommend you would install firebug (http://getfirebug.com/), and see if the script is executing. IE is known to have problems with this type of scripts.

Answer (score 2):

It's because it should be: `$("#example").autocomplete({ source: data })`

It seems the [docs you found](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) is outdated. A more up to date version can be found here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: The autocomplete function accept an object with the attribute source which contains the data. The other attributes include - minlength (no of characters that must be typed before autocomplete triggers) disabled (that disables the autocomplete), delay (no of milliseconds after a keystroke to wait before triggering the autocomplete)and appendto (which element the menu should be appended to).

Comment: The code to initialize the auto-complete with all options would look like this $("#example").autocomplete({ source: data, delay: 10, minlength: 3, appendTo: "#someElem"});
You can reset an option after initialization like so -
("#example").autocomplete("option", "delay", 0);

Comment: Marcus Ekwall, unfortunately it did not resolve the problem. I have added to my original question some details. May be they give you some hint? Thanks for any help!

Comment: @Roman, all the scripts that are included in your example are outdated. Please base your code on one of the examples from http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

try .split(",")

```
 var data = "Core Selectors Attributes Traversing Manipulation CSS Events Effects Ajax Utilities".split(" ,");
```

also attach a sorce

```
$("#example").autocomplete({
                    source: data
                });
```

Comment: What? that first line of code is totally wrong and will return a single value `Array` looking like this: `["Core Selectors Attributes Traversing Manipulation CSS Events Effects Ajax Utilities"]`

Comment: i thought that it would split the array to look like
["core","selectors","traversing"]... if its like u have said then im wrong i admit coz it will only show this one complete sentence as autocomplete option...